# Sql: Distinct clause with dynamic order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, distinct

Is there any way to run this type of query

```
select distinct ri.id, r.RequestDate, count(ri.id) over() as TotalRecords 
   from security.RequestItemView ri
   order by r.RequestDate asc
       case when @SortColumn='RequestDate' and @SortOrder='ASC' then r.RequestDate end asc,
       case when @SortColumn='RequestDate' and @SortOrder='DESC' then r.RequestDate end desc
```

Dynamic `order by` clause works fine until I use `distinct` clause, it gives this error when I use distinct

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified.

I know we have to have the column in select list which is used in order by clause and that is why I am selecting `r.RequestDate` column, I actually don't want to select that column but to make `distict` work I am selecting it but it still doesn't work.

When I replace dynamic ordering with fixed ordering like this

`order by r.RequestDate asc`

it starts working, so basically dynamic `order by` and `distinct` clause together is not working.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure that `count` value makes sense to you? "over nothing" means same value in each row.

Comment: @IvanStarostin . . . This is a fancy (and I think inefficient) way of doing an aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation instead of `distinct`:

```
select ri.id, r.RequestDate, count(ri.id) as TotalRecords 
from security.RequestItemView ri
group by ri.id, r.RequestDate
order by (case when @SortColumn = 'RequestDate' and @SortOrder='ASC' then min(r.RequestDate) end) asc,
         (case when @SortColumn = 'RequestDate' and @SortOrder='DESC' then min(r.RequestDate) end) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any performance difference in `distinct` and `group by`?

Comment: I think that occasionally the optimize might choose different algorithms, so there might be a difference.  But, in general, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon had a great idea but `distinct` apply after the analytic count is computed. (I looked for an authoritative source on that and didn't find one. It makes the sense though.) If that's indeed what you were looking for then you'll want to double-check those totals. See the example below:

```
create table T (n int);
insert into T (n) values (1), (1);

select distinct n, count(n) from T; -- returns 2
select n, count(n) over () from T group by n; -- returns 1
```

http://rextester.com/SSI28665

I think the easiest fix is to wrap it up in a table expression:

```
select id, RequestDate, TotalRecords from (
    select distinct
        ri.id, r.RequestDate, count(ri.id) over() as TotalRecords
        case when @SortColumn = 'RequestDate' and @SortOrder = 'ASC'
             then r.RequestDate end as sort1,
        case when @SortColumn = 'RequestDate' and @SortOrder = 'DESC'
             then r.RequestDate end as sort2
    from security.RequestItemView ri
) as S
order by sort1 asc, sort2 desc;
```

Of course there's potential for the new columns to interfere with distinct-ification. In this case you're already including `RequestDate` in the output so it won't increase the number of rows. Since you have a `@SortColumn` variable I suspect the query you posted doesn't reflect the larger results you're actually working with and the reason I'm noting this caveat.